# Регулярное выражение для буквенно-цифровой строки в 10 символов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, django

Привет. Мне нужно составить выражение для файла urls.py

Get-переменная var может быть буквенно-цифровой строкой в 10 символов.

Ссылка выглядит так

```html
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?var=fea40u7b94
```

Мой вариант примерно такой `url(r'^(?P<var>\w+)$',`

Правильно ли я составил выражение?

Comment: у вас нет ограничения на 10 символов, а также включено подчеркивание `_`

Comment: А так (?P<var>\w+{10})?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы найти десять цифробуквенных символов в конце строки, можно использовать

```
(?P<var>[a-zA-Z0-9]{10})$
```

См. [онлайн-демо выражения](https://regex101.com/r/hojOq3/1).

**Подробности**

- `(?P<var>[a-zA-Z0-9]{10})` - Именная захватывающая группа, находит ровно 10 букв/цифр ASCII
- `$` - конец строки.

Вариации:

- 10 символов после `=`: `=(?P<var>[a-zA-Z0-9]{10})$`
- От 1 до 10 символов: `=(?P<var>[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10})$`
- Если не хотите писать `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, используйте `[^\W_]`.

Comment: Спасибо большое Wiktor  Stribiżew! Работает. Нужно именно с =. Выбираю ваш ответ лучшим

Comment: А какое регулярное выражение полностью для ?var=fea40u7b94   ?

Comment: Попробуйте `\?var=[A-Za-z0-9]{10}$`.

Comment: Странно, на regex101 работает, а в файле urls.py нет url(r'^\?var=[A-Za-z0-9]{10}$', views.index, name='index'). Я неправильно вставил?

Comment: В регулярках для Django должна быть захватывающая группа. Наверно, вам нужна `r'^\?var=(?P<var>[A-Za-z0-9]{10})$'`

Comment: не работает, - не пропускает урл ?var=fea40u7b94

Comment: @MyNick Тут я помочь уже не могу: если проблема не в регулярке, ищите её у себя в коде.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо огромное.